# What methods are quadrature and which not

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, quadrature

According to differential equations terms, one equation can be solved using **quadrature** if integration can be performed to obtain the desired solution, this applies well to separation of variables and certain substitution techniques, but integration is used also in finding integrating factors, and in Laplace transforms. i notice it's not used in solving the characteristic equation in linear ODES, also isn't numerical solutions aproximations to integrals?

A question rose, for what is a method of finding solutions of a differential equation that is not quadrature or that doesn rely on integration to yield a solution? what am i missing?

Comment: Are you sure about the formulation? Quadrature is used to have a contrast to integration, which in the context of ODE is used for their general solution. Quadrature is the simple integration of functions, $\int f(x)\,dx$. Often an ODE is also considered as solved if it can be reduced to quadratures, even if those integrals can no further be reduced symbolically.

Comment: so there is a difference between integration(the solution of a DE) and quadrature being only integration of functions?

Comment: Yes. Integration here means the general removal of derivatives, quadrature originally refers to finding the area under some curve, or making a shape a square or rectangle of the same area. This is a little the same as some people using "surd" to denote the root of a number to distinguish it from the root of some equation. (Which comes from Fibonacci mis-translating "solution" as in the arabic original the same abbreviation was used as for "root".)

Comment: Reading again the question text, the first part seems influenced by the separation-of-variables and the solution formula for first-order linear DE? Variation-of-constants also leads in general to simple integrals, thus to a reduction to quadrature. Reduction-of-order too. And if you use matrix exponentials for linear systems with constant coefficients, then you land again at the first-order linear DE integration formula. Then the eigen-decomposition via characteristic polynomial only serves to evaluate the matrix exponential.